# deleting specific items from TGrid

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

`

```
procedure TfrmFinal.providerBtnClick(Sender: Tobject); 
var
  provider,text: String;
  J: Integer;
  airtimeBtn: TCornerButton;
  products: TJSONArray;
begin
  glPosScreen.DeleteChildren; 
  posScreen.Visible := True;
  tcMain.Visible := False;
  provider := (sender as TCornerButton).Text;
  case frmDataModule.stringIndex(provider,['MTN','VODACOM','CELL C','TELKOM','RINGAS','EASYLOAD'],false) of 
    0:begin                              
      networks := jsonObject.GetValue<TJSONArray>('networks');y
        begin
          products := networks[0].GetValue<TJSONArray>('products') as TJSONArray;at networks position 0
        for j := 0 to products.Count-1 do 
          begin
            text := ansiUppercase(products[J].GetValue<String>
            airtimeBtn := TCornerButton.Create(glPosScreen);
            airtimeBtn.Parent := glPosScreen;
            airtimeBtn.Text := text;
            airtimeBtn.TextSettings.WordWrap := True;
            airtimeBtn.StyleLookup := 'mtnAirtimeBtn';
            airtimeBtn.OnClick := airtimeBtnClick;
            case j mod 3 of                    
            0: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,5);
            1: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,2.5);
            2: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,5,0,2.5);
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    1:begin
      networks := jsonObject.GetValue<TJSONArray>('networks');
        begin
          products := networks[1].GetValue<TJSONArray>('products') as TJSONArray;
          for J := 0 to products.Count-1 do
            begin
              text := ansiUppercase(products[J].GetValue<String>
              airtimeBtn := TCornerButton.Create(glPosScreen);                         
              airtimeBtn.Parent := glPosScreen;
              airtimeBtn.Text := text;
              airtimeBtn.TextSettings.WordWrap := True;
              airtimeBtn.StyleLookup := 'vodacomAirtimeBtn';
              airtimeBtn.OnClick := airtimeBtnClick;
              case j mod 3 of
                0: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,5);
                1: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,2.5);
                2: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,5,0,2.5);
              end;
            end;
        end;
      end;
    2:begin
      networks := jsonObject.GetValue<TJSONArray>('networks');
        begin
          products := networks[2].GetValue<TJSONArray>('products') as TJSONArray;
          for J := 0 to products.Count-1 do
            begin
              text := ansiUppercase(products[J].GetValue<String>
              airtimeBtn := TCornerButton.Create(glPosScreen);
              airtimeBtn.Parent := glPosScreen;
              airtimeBtn.Text := text;                                            
              airtimeBtn.TextSettings.WordWrap := True;
              airtimeBtn.StyleLookup := 'cellCAirtimeBtn';
              airtimeBtn.OnClick := airtimeBtnClick;
              case j mod 3 of
                0: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,5);
                1: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,2.5);
                2: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,5,0,2.5);
              end
            end;
        end;
      end;
    3:begin
      networks := jsonObject.GetValue<TJSONArray>('networks');
        begin
          products := networks[3].GetValue<TJSONArray>('products') as TJSONArray;
          for J := 0 to products.Count-1 do
            begin
              text := ansiUppercase(products[J].GetValue<String>
              airtimeBtn := TCornerButton.Create(glPosScreen);
              airtimeBtn.Parent := glPosScreen;
              airtimeBtn.Text := text;
              airtimeBtn.TextSettings.WordWrap := True;                          
              airtimeBtn.StyleLookup := 'telkomAirtimeBtn';
              airtimeBtn.OnClick := airtimeBtnClick;
              case j mod 3 of
                0: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,5);
                1: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,2.5);
                2: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,5,0,2.5);
              end
            end;
        end;
      end;
    4:begin
      networks := jsonObject.GetValue<TJSONArray>('networks');
        begin
          products := networks[4].GetValue<TJSONArray>('products') as TJSONArray;
          for J := 0 to products.Count-1 do
            begin
              text := ansiUppercase(products[J].GetValue<String>
              airtimeBtn := TCornerButton.Create(glPosScreen);
              airtimeBtn.Parent := glPosScreen;
              airtimeBtn.Text := text;                                           
              airtimeBtn.TextSettings.WordWrap := True;
              airtimeBtn.StyleLookup := 'ringasAirtimeBtn';
              airtimeBtn.OnClick := airtimeBtnClick;
              case j mod 3 of
                0: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,5);
                1: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,2.5);
                2: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,5,0,2.5);
              end
            end;
        end;
      end;
    5:begin
      networks := jsonObject.GetValue<TJSONArray>('networks');
        begin
        products := networks[5].GetValue<TJSONArray>('products') as TJSONArray;
        for J := 0 to products.Count-1 do
          begin
            text := ansiUppercase(products[J].GetValue<String>
            airtimeBtn := TCornerButton.Create(glPosScreen);                      
            airtimeBtn.Parent := glPosScreen;
            airtimeBtn.Text := text;
            airtimeBtn.TextSettings.WordWrap := True;
            airtimeBtn.StyleLookup := 'easyLoadAirtimeBtn';
            airtimeBtn.OnClick := airtimeBtnClick;
            case j mod 3 of
              0: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,5);
              1: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,2.5,0,2.5);
              2: addMargins(airtimeBtn,5,5,0,2.5);
            end
          end;
        end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

`[image]

I have a TGrid in my application. and I have a function which adds default buttons to the grid every time the user navigates to a specific screen. Each time the user clicks to go to the specified screen the default buttons are added again. I got around this by deleting children before I add the default BTNS. How would I only delete the default buttons and keep the rest of the buttons there? (When a user selects a product it populates the grid with the various items for said product and every time I go back to the screen with the grid it is supposed to still have the previous products buttons so the user can easily navigate back to the POS screen and still have the available products there)

```
procedure TfrmFinal.posClick(Sender: TObject); 
    begin
          glPosScreen.DeleteChildren;
          addDefaultBtns;
          tcMain.Visible := false;
          posScreen.Visible := true;
   end;
```

Comment: The answer is in the code you have, but do not show in your question. Please [edit] your question and add related code.

Comment: @TomBrunberg the code is very basic for this section but will add it. Is there a way for me to add an Image to better explain? I think it would be better to explain if I could add an image

Comment: There is a button for adding image to the question. It may not be visible because of your reputations, but I will make it visible.

Comment: The code you added doesn't show the error. Read about [mre] and provide sufficient code that we can replicate the problem.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thank you, I have posted the Image. So basically I need to delete the 'Back', 'main menu' and 'processBtns' everytime a user navigates back to this screen. but I need to keep all the other buttons. but still readd the default buttons at the top.

Comment: If `glPosScreen.DeleteChildren` deletes all buttons, don't delete all children. Delete only the three buttons that you want to delete. Again, if you have other problems, provide sufficient code to replicate it.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I have added the code which populates the grid with the providers products. not 100% sure if that is what you are looking for ?

Comment: Ask yourself, could you reproduce your problem in a new project with only that code? I have no idea what else you have in your project, what settings you have changed in properties etc.

Comment: @TomBrunberg sorry, I added the wrong code snippit, this is the code that adds the buttons

Comment: I cant recreate the problem with just that code as most of the information comes from an Api, I would have to get all the info from the api as well and then I could reproduce the same problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, your question is about the buttons you have on the lower part of your screen, in the scrollable area. That is the green buttons labeled "Back", "Main Menu" and "Process", and the yellow buttons labeled "R2 MTN", "R5 MTN", "R10 MTN" ....

When you call `glPosScreen.DeleteChildren;` all those buttons are deleted, and so you call `addDefaultButtons;` to add back the three green buttons. The problem then is that all those yellow buttons remain missing.

Correction 1: Don't call `DeleteChildren` as you dont want to delete them all.

Correction 2: Don't call `addDefaultButtons` as you already have the three green buttons.

Correction 3: If you need to do changes to the three green buttons, deal with them one by one.